# How to convert binary read/write to non-binary read/write in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, g++

I have some C++ code from somewhere that reads and writes data in binary format. I want to see what it's reading and writing in the file, so I want to convert it's binary read and write to non-binary read and write.  Also, when I convert the binary write to non-binary write, I want it to still be able to read in the information correctly.  How can this be done?

The write function:

```
int btwrite(short rrn, BTPAGE *page_ptr)
{
//    long lseek(), addr;
    long addr;
    addr = (long) rrn * (long) PAGESIZE + HEADERSIZE;
    lseek(btfd, addr, 0);
    return (write(btfd, page_ptr, PAGESIZE));
}
```

The read function:

```
int btread(short rrn, BTPAGE *page_ptr)
{
//  long lseek(), addr;
    long addr;

    addr = (long)rrn * (long)PAGESIZE + HEADERSIZE;
    lseek(btfd, addr, 0);
    return ( read(btfd, page_ptr, PAGESIZE) );
}
```

Here is the definition of BTPAGE:

```
typedef struct {
    short keycount;             /* number of keys in page   */
    int  key[MAXKEYS];              /* the actual keys      */
    short child[MAXKEYS+1];     /* ptrs to rrns of descendants  */
} BTPAGE;
```

Comment: Need more details, especially `BTPAGE`.

Comment: I'm gonna take this opportunity to plug Google's protocol buffers: http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Comment: Is it sufficient to write a tool to inspect the binary file format, or do you need to see it from the writer program?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, add an overloaded stream insertion operator to the BTPAGE class.  After you read the BTPage, add the following:

```
  cout << *page_ptr << endl;
```

Otherwise you will have to edit your questions with more details about what you are looking for.  For example:

1. Do you want the data read to be
   output in 1's and 0's?
2. Do you want a byte by byte dump?

Also, please provide the declaration of BTPAGE.

Comment: I don't want to see binary I want to see actual values before they are converted to binary and written to disk.